# having trouble sending mail in asp.net core 5 App

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I searched many post for sending mails. I am trying to create a mail sender service. I tried two methods.

**Method 1:**

```
public class MailSender : IMailSender
{
    public async Task SendMail(string to = null, string title = null, string body = null)
    {
        var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
        {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("mygmail@gmail.com", "password"),
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
        };
        client.SendAsync("mygmail@gmail.com", to, title, body, "mail send success");
    }
}
```

**Method 2:**

```
public class MailSender : IMailSender
{
    public async Task SendMail(string to = null, string title = null, string body = null)
    {
        MailAddress sender = new MailAddress("mygmail@gmail.com");
        MailAddress reciver = new MailAddress(to);
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        message.From = sender;
        message.To.Add(reciver);            
        message.Subject = title;
        message.Body = body;

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential()
        { Password = "password", UserName = "mygmail@gmail.com" };
        await smtp.SendMailAsync(message);            
    }       
}
```

I don't know why its not working. There are no exceptions thrown, and all Google security setting are set.

Comment: What is not working? Do you get an exception?

Comment: no noting it don't throw any exception it just don't send mail

Comment: all security related setting in google account are set

Comment: Have you registered the implementation for the service as a transient in Startup (configure services)? If so, are breakpoints getting hit?

Comment: yes I did those the service is added as transient and breakpoint get hit

Comment: How do you call these methods from controller action?

Comment: using dependency injection in constructor of controller and calling the method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

guys i don't know why it wasnt work earlier
but i rewrite the code like this and it worked sorry

```
namespace MyShop.Services
{
    public class MailSender : IMailSender
    {
        public async Task SendMail(string FromApp,string ToUser, string Title, string MailBody,string Password)
        {
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
            {
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(FromApp, Password),
                EnableSsl = true,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
            };

            MailMessage mail = new
                MailMessage(FromApp,ToUser ,Title ,MailBody);
            smtpClient.SendAsync(mail, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had a code on .net Core 3.1 that was working there, but when using it with .net core 5 was giving me this error: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 Client not authenticated to send mail.   Changing the code to this resolve the issue.

Comment: if you use gamil for sending email you should turn on allow less secure app in your google account security settings